# adding more than one slider in joomla on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to add a image carousel to my joomla page which already has a DJimage slider(for the banner)I have tried many carousel but none is working.Is there any problem in adding two script to the same page in joomla(I read it some where but can't find the solution) if yes than what is the solution.I am using joomla 2.5.

Thanks

Comment: Any javascript errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try bxSlider i think this is what you need.
http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides

Answer (score 0):

You can publish any number of DJ-ImageSlider at the page. It is a joomla module so you just need to create new instance of the module (module manager -> new -> DJ-ImageSlider) or copy it  and change the settings. You have to assign the module to desired menu items and publish it in existing module position.

Comment: thanks for the advise but i need a different kind of so i can't use djimage slider and i have done that at some other place and it's work fine. But when I am adding some other extension(Hot image slider,bootstrap slider)and even the slider which I have codede it is causing problem.

Comment: You can use bootstrap
I am using bootstrap 3 slider on a page and it work fine...

Just make sure you use differnet ids for each slider...

Comment: I am also using bootstrap slider but it's not working properly,I am displaying total 8 images displaying 4 at a time it display the first 4 alright but for the next 4 it disappears(slider height becomes 0 and margin -ive) while the same code is working fine in other file(non joomla files).